# HP pavilion p7-1110 giving beeps after trying to install new graphics card

Tags: hp-pavilion

I have an HP pavilion p7-1110 that I'm trying to install a new graphics card into, but it is giving me 3 beeps with about 15-30 seconds in-between then a beep and 3 beeps consecutively with about 1 second in-between them. The graphics card is a EVGA GeForce GT 710 brand new.

The computer starts up but does not make it passed the HP screen. I'm running Windows10 on this computer and I've attempted to run in Legacy mode but that has failed. I've also tried resetting the CMOS. Can anyone help me or tell me if you think the graphics card is DOA?

Thank you in advanced.

EDIT: 
The PSU is 450w and is more than adequate for the entire system, all cables are correctly plugged in and, as far as I know it does, but I have no other computer to check it on either.

Comment: Have you verified all cables connections?  Have you verified your PSU is adequate enough for your GPU?  If you install the previous GPU does your system boot?  Are you sure the GPU actually works?  It being brand new doesn't mean much when dealing with hardware released more than 4 years ago.  Edit your question, do not submit a comment.  The 3 long beeps indicate "no video" by the way

Comment: Suspect the code you are actually getting is: [2 short beeps and 1 long beep (repeats 5 times) which stands for Unable to initialize video or video card required but not installed](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02222922)

Comment: So with those three long beeps saying that there is no video, is there a way to fix it, or does that mean the graphics card is already gone?